# How to defeat the boss in chapter 9 of Dead Space 3?

Tags: dead-space-3

I'm playing on Normal difficulty and am getting hammered trying to defeat the boss in Chapter 9.  How are people defeating this enemy?

The IGN walkthrough just says it's "easier said than done", to stay out of its reach and use the quick sprint to roll out of its way.  All that is standard, I'm wondering more about the weapon choices people are using.  I'm using the Evangelizer and Negotiator.

Comment: Omg, I just saw this video where the person handled it with no effort at all.  What weapon is that, and what level of stasis are they at?  [link](http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=PF7M2BTJ1l4&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPF7M2BTJ1l4)

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like the Evangelizer.  I swear I've shot the thing's mouth tentacles off after it regenerates, but it doesn't run away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been running from the beast, trying to keep the rock formation in the center of the arena between me and it, turning to blast it when I thought it was a safe distance away.  More often than not, it would knock me down from behind, depleting my health and slowing my steps to the point that it would wear me down.

Seeing this video, where susan2010x simply stood her ground and blasted it with the Evangelizer shotgun and stasis gave me the courage to try that technique, and I did it on the first try!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be as complicated as that.  Using any high rate-of-fire weapon will do it.  Using a carbine will suffice.  When the tentacles come out, fire at the yellow points of one.  Once it's been taking off, run perpendicular to the monster in case he charges, then turn around and do it again.  Once all three of them are gone, it will spawn three glowing sacs from it's mouth and charge you.  This is the only time I needed to use stasis.  Slow him down, shoot a sac, then keep going.  Rinse and repeat.  Once you have two down, you're good.

Again, Evangilizer works, but I used an SMG or normal carbine to do this.

Comment: Do you know if the first set of tentacles regenerate if you don't get them all quickly enough?  That's the only explanation I can think of that might explain my initial difficulties...that my running around the rock formation gave it time to heal, and so I was wasting health and resources continually shooting off those tentacles, not the final set.

Comment: I found that they will not regenerate if you're still trying to knock off the first set.  However, when the sacs in his mouth appear, you only get one shot at taking one of them out.  If you miss, he retracts them and regenerates all of his back tentacles.